# UINavigationController not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I was using a `UITabBar` for my application but (for my own reasons) I had to remove it. Now none of my `UINavigationControllers` work. Where that manifests itself most is when I call:    `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];`

That code now does nothing because I have no `UINavigationController` and I don't know how to make one that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{             
    //Initialize window components
    UINavigationController *myNavController     = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self setNavController: myNavController];
    [myNavController release];

    FirstViewController *cViewController    = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [self setMyFirstView: cViewController];
    [cViewController release];

    [self.window addSubview: [self navController].view];

    [[self navController] pushViewController: myFirstView animated:YES];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This should do the trick.

By the way, you should declare the following for that in the delegate.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CatchengoViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *myFirstView;
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It worked right away after I had wasted hours trying to figure it out by my self. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a navigation controller and add it to the view as a subview or initialise it with your main view controller.
It can be done from IB too. Google for navigation based app sample code for more info.